# Koa Context Mutation via Middleware

Tags: node.js, typescript, koa

I have a Koa server written in Typescript. I would like to write middleware to parse request bodies and pass them to routes through the context. In order to do this, I would have to mutate the context type via middleware. Does anyone know if this is possible, or of a better way to handle this? I know I could just write a body parsing function and call it within the route, but middleware seems like an appropriate place to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: There is the koa-bodyparser package, and there is also @types/koa-bodyparser, and if you look at the type definition, it adds some things to the Request interface so `ctx.request.body` is defined.

Comment: @qrsngky unfortunately this looks like kind of a hack, as it re-declares the Request interface on import. technically this would make the `body` and `rawBody` parameters accessible before the `bodyParser()` method is called

Comment: > Does anyone know if this is possible, or of a better way to handle this
   
yes koa definitely encourages mutation of the context. just be careful that you validate the correct type when updating the context so your typescript types are accurate at run time

Answer (score 0):

I looked into Koa's types, and it seems that the `State` typing is the answer. Koa middleware can be typed and include modifications to Koa's `state` parameter. this can be accomplished by typing the application like so

```
const app = new Koa<{}, KoaContext>()
```

where the empty object means an empty state.

Then, the middleware can be typed like so

```
module MyMiddleware {
  export const parseBodyMiddleware: Middleware<MyBodyType> = async (ctx, next) => {
    const body: MyBodyType = ...
    ctx.state = body
    await next();
  };
}
```

this types koa's `ctx.state` with `MyBodyType`. Currently there's no enforcement requiring the middleware to update state with that type, but will update if I find a solution there.